# DevTestLab: Running sysprep artifact not deallocating the VM

Tags: azure, artifacts, azure-devtest-labs

I am running sysprep artifact on my VM through my code -

```
az lab vm apply-artifacts ...
```

It is showing up as succeeded when I check it from the portal. 
When I check more details about the artifact, it doesn't show me any error. The only extension message I see is:

```
/generalize /oobe /shutdown
```

Yet it is not deallocated. When I run sysprep again on the same VM from the portal, it works fine - the VM stops and gets deallocated.

Not sure what is happening or how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

When a VM shuts down on its own, it is not deallocated - this is the expected behavior.  The Stop button in the Azure portal shuts down the VM and deallocates it.  If using PowerShell Stop-AzureRmVM, you can pass in the `-StayProvisioned` parameter to control this.